How to correctly search products variations with product tags in WooCommerce?
I have a plugin I created to search for products with variants. I want to handle the case when a customer selects "contains poultry" in the survey, then he searches for a product that contains this tag.
If I don't select anything, I want it to search for a product without tags
When I select, for example, the exclusion of rabbit, it searches for a product with this tag
When I select, for example, the exclusion of rabbit and poultry, it searches for products with these tags (together)
Currently searching for products with variants, but searching by tags does not work. Could you please help me?
{
    // Input data validation
    $survey_data = isset($_POST['survey_data']) ? $_POST['survey_data'] : [];
    if (empty($survey_data)) {
        wp_send_json_error('No data provided.');
    }

    $dog_weight = isset($survey_data['dog_weight']) ? floatval($survey_data['dog_weight']) : 0;
    if ($dog_weight <= 0) {
        wp_send_json_error('Invalid dog weight.');
    }

    // Selecting the product variant based on the dog's weight
    $variant_weight = '';
    if ($dog_weight >= 1 && $dog_weight <= 4) {
        $variant_weight = '150g';
    } elseif ($dog_weight > 4 && $dog_weight <= 8) {
        $variant_weight = '200g';
    } elseif ($dog_weight > 8 && $dog_weight <= 15) {
        $variant_weight = '300g';
    } elseif ($dog_weight > 15 && $dog_weight <= 24) {
        $variant_weight = '400g';
    } elseif ($dog_weight > 24 && $dog_weight <= 35) {
        $variant_weight = '500g';
    } elseif ($dog_weight > 35) {
        wp_send_json_error('No products matching the criteria.');
    }

    // Preparing the query
    $args = [
        'post_type' => 'product_variation', // OR product
        'posts_per_page' => 1, // Fetches 6 products
        //'tax_query' => [
        //    [
        //        'key' => 'pa_gramatura', // Meta key for the "weight" attribute (WooCommerce saves attributes as 'pa_attribute_name')
        //        'value' => $variant_weight,       // Value we are looking for
        //        'compare' => '='         // Comparison operator
        //    ]
        //],
        'meta_query' => [
            [
                'key' => 'attribute_pa_gramatura', // Meta key for the "weight" attribute
                'value' => $variant_weight,       // Value we are looking for
                'compare' => '='                  // Comparison operator
            ]
        ],
    ];

    // Adding exclusions based on allergies
    $allergy_map = [
        'dog_allergy_milk' => 'contains-dairy',
        'dog_allergy_gluten' => 'contains-gluten',
        'dog_allergy_lactose' => 'contains-lactose',
        'dog_allergy_poultry' => 'contains-poultry',
        'dog_allergy_pork' => 'contains-pork',
        'dog_allergy_beef' => 'contains-beef',
        'dog_allergy_horseflesh' => 'contains-horsemeat',
        'dog_allergy_venison' => 'contains-venison',
        'dog_allergy_rabbit' => 'contains-rabbit',
        'dog_allergy_boar' => 'contains-boar'
    ];

    if (!empty($survey_data['dog_allergies'])) {
        $tax_query = ['relation' => 'AND'];

        foreach ($survey_data['dog_allergies'] as $allergy) {
            if (isset($allergy_map[$allergy])) {
                $tax_query[] = [
                    'taxonomy' => 'product_tag',
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => $allergy_map[$allergy], // Dynamic assignment from the map
                    'operator' => 'IN',          // Include products with this tag
                ];
            }
        }

        $args['tax_query'] = $tax_query;
    }

    // Executing the query
    $query = new WP_Query($args);
    $products = [];

    if ($query->have_posts()) {
        while ($query->have_posts()) {
            $query->the_post();

            $product = wc_get_product(get_the_ID());

            $image_url = '';
            $parent_product = wc_get_product($product->get_parent_id());

            // Fetch the main product image if available
            if ($parent_product && has_post_thumbnail($parent_product->get_id())) {
                $image_url = get_the_post_thumbnail_url($parent_product->get_id(), 'medium');
            }
            // If the main image is not available, fetch the variant's image
            elseif (has_post_thumbnail($product->get_id())) {
                $image_url = get_the_post_thumbnail_url($product->get_id(), 'medium');
            }
            // If no image is set, use a placeholder image
            else {
                $image_url = wp_get_attachment_url(8448);
            }

            $products[] = [
                'title' => get_the_title(),
                'description' => wc_get_product($product->get_parent_id())->get_short_description(),
                'image' => $image_url,
                'price' => $product->get_price(),
                'url' => get_permalink(),
                'gramatura' => $variant_weight,
            ];
        }
        wp_reset_postdata();

        wp_send_json_success($products);
    } else {
        wp_send_json_error('No products matching the criteria.');
    }

    wp_die();
}`````


Note that product tags are assigned to the parent variable product, never to a product variation.
